# Getting error on host_processor_sets swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I don't know why i am getting this error

```
var list                         = [ProcessInfo]()
var psets                        = processor_set_name_array_t.allocate(capacity: 1)
var pcnt: mach_msg_type_number_t = 0

var result = host_processor_sets(machHost, &psets, &pcnt)
```

the last statement gives :

> cannot pass immutable value of type as inout argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `host_processor_sets` is imported into Swift as:

```
func host_processor_sets(
    _ host_priv: host_priv_t,
    _ processor_sets: UnsafeMutablePointer<processor_set_name_array_t?>!,
    _ processor_setsCnt: UnsafeMutablePointer<mach_msg_type_number_t>!
) -> kern_return_t
```

(Taken from the Quick Help of Xcode.)

When you find an `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>!` in imported C-function, you usually declare a variable of type `T` and pass it as an inout parameter.

So, you need to declare variables of `processor_set_name_array_t?` and `mach_msg_type_number_t`.

```
var psets: processor_set_name_array_t? = nil
var pcnt: mach_msg_type_number_t = 0
var result = host_processor_sets(machHost, &psets, &pcnt)
```