# host_processor_sets returning KERN_INVALID_ARGUMENT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, bsd

I am running the below code in Xcode and also I have selected root in the run scheme for the below code

```
fileprivate static let machHost = mach_host_self()
var psets: processor_set_name_array_t? = nil
var pcnt: mach_msg_type_number_t = 0
withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &psets) { psetptr in
    var result = host_processor_sets(machHost, psetptr, &pcnt)
}
```

However the variable `result` always return 4 (`KERN_INVALID_ARGUMENT`), but I expected 0 (`KERN_SUCCESS`).

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40598162/1187415

Answer (score 1):

The type, `processor_set_name_array_t`, is defined like this:

```swift
public typealias processor_set_name_array_t = UnsafeMutablePointer<processor_set_t>
```

So it's already a pointer type.  `host_processor_sets` is expecting a pointer to space allocated to hold a consecutive sequence of `processor_set_t` elements.

However, when you do

```swift
withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &psets) { psetptr in
    var result = host_processor_sets(machHost, psetptr, &pcnt)
}
```

`psetptr` is `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer< processor_set_t>>`, which is to say that it is a pointer to the pointer that points to the `processor_set_t` elements.  If you're familiar with C, you're passing a `processor_set_t**` to a function expecting `processor_set_t*`.

Assuming that passing `nil` is OK - it usually is in order to just get the number of elements to allocate space for, but documentation is a bit lacking - then what you want is this:

```swift
fileprivate static let machHost = mach_host_self()
var pcnt: mach_msg_type_number_t = 0
var result = host_processor_sets(machHost, nil, &pcnt)
```

Once you have `pcnt` if you want to retrieve the `processor_set_t` elements themselves, you should be able to do it like this:

```swift
var psets = [processor_set_t](repeating: .init(), count: Int(pcnt));
result = psets.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer {
    host_processor_sets(machHost, $0.baseAddress, &pcnt)
}
```